# iframe video don't stop running even after page refresh

Tags: php, jquery

our requirement is like this website - https://www.last.fm/music, where on even page change(refresh) youtube video continues playing. How is that possible.

We had tried youtube iframe api it is not providing something like this. it might be related to jquery window load events or any video player

Comment: the whole design of the website is different, its a single page application. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application

Comment: But if you check code its php based website, how do you get to know its single page web application ?

Comment: yes you were right its a single page application, page is not refrshing or reloading thats why video keeps running. Thanks Man!

Answer (score 1):

Are you using jQuery? You can track the time of the video before the refresh with something like this:

```
$('body').bind('beforeunload',function(){
   // track current time and store it in cookie or other
});
```

Then on page load you can update the video url with the time in seconds like:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VIDEO_ID#t=TIME_IN_SECONDS